# While loop only showing 1 result

Tags: php

I have a script that checks for dupe values in db and loops through the result and echoes the value using json. However, it is only displaying 1 record instead of 3 which is being sent to php. I would be grateful if someone could point out my error. Thanks

```
$boxitems = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['box']);
$array = array();
$array = $boxitems;

foreach ($array as $boxes) {

    $sql = "SELECT item FROM act WHERE item = '".$boxes."' GROUP BY item HAVING COUNT(*) > 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Error selecting item: ' . mysqli_error());
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
      if($num_rows) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
              $data[] =  $row['item'];
          }
          echo '<div style="width: 50%; margin-bottom: 20px; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid black; background: red; font-size: 16px; color: white; height: 50px; padding: 15px; line-height: 1.3;">';
          echo json_encode($data)  . ' already exists. Please enter a unique box reference.';
          echo '</div>';
          exit;
        } else {
          echo '<div style="width: 50%; margin-bottom: 20px; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid black; background: #63c84c; font-size: 16px; color: white; height: 50px; padding: 15px; line-height: 1.3;">';
          echo 'No dupes found in database.';
          echo '</div>';
          exit;
        }
    }
```

[image]

**UPDATED** screen shot

[image]

Comment: You are using `exit;` inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks for reply. Where should I use `exit`;. Thanks

Comment: `exit;` terminates the script, so only use it when you want to stop the script.

Comment: on this case you must not use it, the loop will stop by itself when it can't reach $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result), so there's no reason for using an exit here.

Comment: What's the point of using `mysqli_real_escape_string` with array? Or if `$_POST['box']` is not array - then what's the point of using `foreach` on it?

Comment: @u_mulder yeh just picked that up myself. Thanks for spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put what your want to echo into a single variable that is declared outside the foreach and concatenate each div (one for each loop your foreach does). And then echo it after the loop.

```
$boxitems = $_POST['box'];
$insertedItems = array();
$duplicateItems = array();

foreach ($boxitems as $boxes) {

    $escapedBoxes = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $boxes);   
    $sql = "SELECT item FROM act WHERE item = '".$escapedBoxes."' GROUP BY item HAVING COUNT(*) > 0";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Error selecting item: ' . mysqli_error());
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($num_rows) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $duplicateItems[] = $row['item'];
        }            
    }
    else
    {
        $insertedItems[] = $escapedBoxes;
    }
}   

if(!empty($duplicateItems)) {
    echo '<div style="width: 50%; margin-bottom: 20px; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid black; background: red; font-size: 16px; color: white; height: 50px; padding: 15px; line-height: 1.3;">';
    echo json_encode($duplicateItems)  . ' already exists. Please enter a unique box reference.';
    echo '</div>';
} else {
    echo '<div style="width: 50%; margin-bottom: 20px; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid black; background: #63c84c; font-size: 16px; color: white; height: 50px; padding: 15px; line-height: 1.3;">';
    echo 'No dupes found in database.<br/>';
    echo json_encode($insertedItems) . ' has been entered successfully into the database.';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

**EDIT: Updated code considering u_mulder comment.**

Comment: Thank you Parmifer. However, it is not echoing any data.

Comment: Can you var_dump($data) after the while loop and tell me if it's empty or not ? Thanks.

Comment: I have added screenshot to show what is being output. I shall try var_dump now. Thanks

Comment: Here is the result of `var_dump($data);` `array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "aaa" }` It is only showing 1 item and i entered 2

Comment: and this is the output of `array = $boxitems;` `array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "aaa" [1]=> string(3) "ggg" } `

Comment: I updated my answer, try it out. And can you tell me what is in your database please?

Comment: I already amended the code for $boxitems being an array. I shall now try your code. I also changed the `> 1 to > 0` and try that.

Comment: Changing the `> 1 to > 0` got further but it is creating a div for each item. I only need to create 1 div with all items not separate. Thanks I have posted updated screenshot

Comment: It's quite simple then, store all your positive match in an array. If it's empty that means you have no dupes found. Please see updated code.

Comment: The problem that now creates is that the second div is outside the for loop so only 1 item getting displayed. The first div is working fine. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166520/discussion-between-parmifer-and-user1532468).

Answer (score 0):

```
$boxitems = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['box']);
$array = array();
$array = $boxitems;

foreach ($array as $boxes) {

    $sql = "SELECT item FROM act WHERE item = '".$boxes."' GROUP BY item HAVING COUNT(*) > 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Error selecting item: ' . mysqli_error());
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
      if($num_rows) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
              $data[] =  $row['item'];
          }
          echo '<div style="width: 50%; margin-bottom: 20px; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid black; background: red; font-size: 16px; color: white; height: 50px; padding: 15px; line-height: 1.3;">';
          echo json_encode($data)  . ' already exists. Please enter a unique box reference.';
          echo '</div>';
          exit;
        } else {
          echo '<div style="width: 50%; margin-bottom: 20px; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid black; background: #63c84c; font-size: 16px; color: white; height: 50px; padding: 15px; line-height: 1.3;">';
          echo 'No dupes found in database.';
          echo '</div>';
        }
     exit;
    }
```

An exit inside any function, loop or condition will make the program to go out of it and continue, so it's not iterating through, it's exiting after the first iteration.

Comment: you missed an `exit`

Comment: `continue` what?

Comment: you didn't need to copy all of OP's code.  Also i don't see the need for exit though

Comment: If I remove exit; no data is returned at all. I cannot see any other place I can place the exit;? Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to put an exit anyway, it can be something wrong on another place?

Comment: Still the same. Nothing returned. Thanks

Comment: If i remove exits fro code it displays the first item as error then just also print the next div in the else statement. It should be displaying value of dupe items from the select statement.